# Is there an objective-C library to talk with a CAS server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, cas

Is there a library already created to talk with an CAS server via objective-c? I know there are many supported [clients](http://www.jasig.org/cas/client-integration/other-clients) but have yet to find anything I can use on the iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gibbs.acu.edu/2009/03/20/iphone-cas-auth/

Answer (score 1):

The code mentioned http://gibbs.acu.edu/2009/03/20/iphone-cas-auth/ is now hosted at GitHub. You can check it out here: https://github.com/acu-dev/objc-cas-client

Note: I haven't touched it in a couple years and I'm sure it could be overhauled so feel free to fork it or make suggestions.